# C++ Derived class function redefinition

Tags: c++

member function void readPayInfo() is redefined in class BonusEmployee. It now returns the value of the data member base pay plus the value of the data member bonus

```
class Employee
{
public:
      //constructors here
      void readPayInfo()
      {cin >> basePay;}
private:
      double basePay;
};


class BonusEmployee : public Employee
{
public:
      //constructors here
      void readPayInfo()
      {cin >> basePay >> bonus;} // NULL!
private:
      bonus;
};
```

how do I access basePay from parent class?

Comment: You don't, unless you change it to be `protected`, or add a ["setter" function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method).

Comment: And `readPayInfo` be `virtual`

Comment: wow thanks you guys are reaaaaaally fast responders

Comment: "how do I access basePay from parent class?". You meant Derived or Child class, Because Employee is the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've opted to make `Employee::basePay` private there is no way to directly access it from a subclass.  I think you have two options:

1. Add a getter to `Employee`, or
2. Change the visibility of `Employee::basePay` to `protected`.

Comment: ^ you're awesome changing it to protected worked. ;_;